# Why are gradient descent results so far off lm results?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I´m playing around with the `gradDescent` package on some made up data to get a feel for it. As I understand it, I should be getting similar results from both linear regression and gradient descent when I apply in on same data that is generated from a linear equation, but the outputs are wildly different.

While `lm` gives me reasonable estimates of the three coeffiecients (all of which were set to 5), gradient descent seems to be acting up. I don´t think the dataset in question needs feature scaling, so I didn´t use it, which resulted in estimated coeffiecients on the order of 10^22. When I added feature scaling, all estimated coefficients dropped under 1. Either way, I can´t seem to get a result even remotely close to the expected ones.

(I´ve tried shutting off the session and starting again, but the results were the same.)

This is how the dataset is generated:

```
N <- 100
n <- 10

x1 <- runif(N, 12, 40)
x2 <- runif(N, 10, 35)
x3 <- runif(N, 8, 25)

coef <- 5

dev <- 5

y <- coef*x1 + coef*x2 + coef*x3 + rnorm(N, 0, dev)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3, y))
names(data) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y")
```

I´m using `gradDescent` for the gradient descent algorithm, using the following versions.

```
gradDescentR.learn(data, featureScaling = TRUE,
scalingMethod = "MINMAX", learningMethod = "GD", control = list(),
seed = NULL)

gradDescentR.learn(data, featureScaling = FALSE,
scalingMethod = "MINMAX", learningMethod = "GD", control = list(),
seed = NULL)
```

I would expect `gradDescent` to return values around 5 for the coefficients. I´m fairly certain the problem lies somewhere in the function settings (that is, me setting them incorrectly), but I can´t figure out where.

Thank you.

Comment: Try toying a bit with the control settings (the learning rate and the amount of iterations). For me, setting the learning rate to 0.001 and the maxIter to 100 gives pretty good results

Comment: In general, gradient descent will converge to a local minima, while lm solves for the global minima. Also, lm works best when the error distribution is gaussian.